# image 404 (not found) Github Pages Vitejs build React app not show the image

Tags: reactjs, image, http-status-code-404, github-pages, vite

I am trying to make a simple React app with ViteJS and GitHub Pages but something is wrong with my images. I can't load them, event although I added them to assets folder. Can you help me how to fix that ?

[when vite priview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPhpE.png)

[vite.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2nip.png)

that is my project, please help me
https://github.com/quocbinh-npm9081/React-App-Space-tourism-website

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the correct url for your images you are using the path https://quocbinh-npm9081.github.io/assets/destination/image-titan.png where as it should be https://quocbinh-npm9081.github.io/React-App-Space-tourism-website/assets/destination/image-titan.png

Github pages deploys your site in your project sub-directory

You should build your site accordingly to be hosted in a sub-directory

Answer (score 0):

Additionnaly, the [vite doc](https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html#github-pages) say :

> If you are deploying to `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/`, you can omit base as it defaults to '/'.

```
export default defineConfig(
  // base: ''
}
```

> If you are deploying to `https://<USERNAME>.github.io/<REPO>/`, for example your repository is at `https://github.com/<USERNAME>/<REPO>`, then set base to `'/<REPO>/'`.

```
export default defineConfig(
  base: '/React-App-Space-tourism-website/'
}
```

then in your case:
`git push -f git@github.com:<USERNAME>/<REPO>.git master:gh-pages`